# Apache Xerces throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using XSAttributeUse.getValueConstraintValue()

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces, nosuchmethoderror

My task is to pull out a (name, default value) pair of every optional attribute in a given complex type.
I have the following piece of code:

```
XSObjectList attrList = typeDefinition.getAttributeUses();
for (int i = 0; i < attrList.getLength(); i++) {
    XSAttributeUse attributeUse = (XSAttributeUse) attrList.item(i);

    if (!attributeUse.getRequired()) {
        String name = attributeUse.getValueConstraintValue().getNormalizedValue();
        String value = /* extracting the default value */;
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/xerces/xs/XSAttributeUse.getValueConstraintValue()Lorg/apache/xerces/xs/XSValue; (loaded from path\to\sdk\jre\lib\xml.jar by <Bootstrap Loader>) called from class my.package.xsd.XSDParser (loaded from file:/path/to/the/project/SwidSigner/target/classes/ by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@29b444c2).
    at my.package.xsd.XSDParser.getTypeAttributes(XSDParser.java:54)
    at my.package.xsd.XSDParser.getAttributes(XSDParser.java:37)
    at my.package.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

What's more, when I change it to:

```
XSObjectList attrList = typeDefinition.getAttributeUses();
for (int i = 0; i < attrList.getLength(); i++) {
    XSAttributeUse attributeUse = (XSAttributeUse) attrList.item(i);
    XSAttributeDeclaration attributeDecl = attributeUse.getAttrDeclaration();

    if (!attributeUse.getRequired()) {
        String name = attributeDecl.getValueConstraintValue().getNormalizedValue();
        String value = /* extracting the default value */;
    }
}
```

The error still occurs, but it complains about XSAttributeDeclaration class instead. There is no error when using other methods, such as

```
XSComplexTypeDefinition.getAttributeUses()
```

I'm using Maven to import Xerces:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? It looks like its attempting to load a Xerces class from your JRE's lib directory.

Comment: I'm using Java 8. How do I make it load Xerces class from Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You have a rogue jar with Xerces classes in it.

Check your installed JRE's lib directory. It appears that it is loading the class in question from a jar called `xml.jar`. I'm not sure where this jar came from as I do not see it in any Java installations I am currently working with (Java 8 on both Linux an OSX).

If you delete (or move) this jar, the problem should be resolved. Note that this may have unintended consequences on other Java programs on your system.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchMethodError` means that there's code that was present in your compile-time classpath that isn't present in your run-time classpath. Check for any differences. If you're using an IDE that generates the "import"s for you, check that it's importing the packages you expect to be using.